# Generate PDF with Rotativa including charts not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts, rotativa

I'm having trouble creating a PDF with Rotativa in my ASP.NET MVC app. The problem is with adding Highcharts-based charts to the PDF – everything else shows up fine, but the charts are missing.

1. button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning"> <i class="fa fa-print"></i> <span class="bold"> @Html.ActionLink(@.LocalResource.Resource.Print, "ConvertToPDF", "Monitoring", new { id = 1 }, new { @Style = "color: white;", @target = "_blank" })</span></button>
```

1. controller:

```
  public ActionResult header(int id)
  {
      ViewBag.Header = id == 1 ? LocalResource.Resource.TransactionsReport : "Vue Gab";
      return View();
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult ConvertToPDF(int id)
  {
      ViewBag.HideLayout = 1;

      //string cusomtSwitches = string.Format(" --print-media-type --page-offset 2 --footer-center [page] --allow {0} --footer-html {0} --footer-spacing -180 ",
      //    Url.Action("header", "CashView"));

      UriBuilder u = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
      {
          Path = Url.Action("header", "Monitoring", new { id = id }),
          Query = null
      };

      //Format the header to read Test.cshtml file
      string t = string.Format("--header-html {0}", u.Uri.ToString());
      string customSwitches = "--enable-javascript --debug-javascript --no-stop-slow-scripts --javascript-delay 10000";

      var model = new object();
      if (id == 1)
      {
          model = modelTrnsReport;
      }
      else
      {
          model = homeModel;
      }

      var pdf = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf
      {
          ViewName = (id == 1 ? "PdftransactionReport" : ""),
          Model = model,
          FileName = (id == 1 ? "Transactions Report" : "Vue Gab") + DateTime.Now.Date + ".pdf",
          PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
          PageMargins = new Margins(35, 10, 20, 10),
          PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,

          //"--viewport-size 1000x1000"
          CustomSwitches = customSwitches

      };

      return pdf;
  }
```

1. pdf view that generate :

```
@model Website.Areas.AVMonitoring.Models.TransactionReportModel


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="background:none">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title" style="margin-bottom:2px">
                        <h5></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <h3 class="no-margins">
                            @Website.LocalResource.Resource.RateofsuccessfulTransaction : @Model.RateofsuccessfulTransaction %
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title" style="margin-bottom:2px">
                        <h5></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content col-xs-pull-12">
                        <h3 style="text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="no-margins">@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Numberof Transaction : @Model.TransactionNumber</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row match-height">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content collapse show match-height">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="bs-callout-light bg-light  callout-border-left p-1">
                                <strong>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.TransactionByType</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" ">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div id="chart_transaction_type"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="table-responsive" style="font-size: 1.2rem">
                                    <table class=" table table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr style="font-size: 13px">
                                                <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Transactiontype</th>
                                                <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.NumberOfTransactions</th>
                                                <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Rate  </th>
                                                <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.color  </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionTypeGraphData)
                                            {
                                                <tr style="font-size: 11px">
                                                    <th scope="row">

                                                        @if (Session["lang"] == "en")
                                                        {
                                                            @item.highlight
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            @item.label_fr
                                                        }
                                                        @*@item.highlight*@
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>@item.count</td>
                                                    <td>@item.value %</td>
                                                    <td style="background:@item.color"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content collapse show match-height">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="bs-callout-light bg-light  callout-border-left p-1">
                                <strong>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.RejectIssues</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" ">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div id="chart_Motif_Rejet"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" ">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr style="font-size: 13px">
                                                    <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Rejecttype</th>
                                                    <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.NumberOfTransactions</th>
                                                    <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Rate  </th>
                                                    <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.color  </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model.RejectedTransactionList)
                                                {
                                                    <tr style="font-size: 11px">
                                                        <th scope="row">
                                                            @if (Session["lang"] == "en")
                                                            {
                                                                @item.highlight
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                @item.label_fr
                                                            }
                                                            @*@item.highlight*@

                                                            @*@item.highlight*@

                                                        </th>
                                                        <td>@item.count</td>
                                                        <td>@item.value %</td>
                                                        <td style="background:@item.color"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <P CLASS="breakhere"></P>
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.ATM A</th>
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Rateofsuccess </th>
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Numberof TRX</th>
                        @*<th>Total @Website.LocalResource.Resource.Withdrawal</th>*@
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Withdrawal</th>
                        @*<th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Withdrawal @Website.LocalResource.Resource.withoutcard </th>*@
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Other types </th>
                        <th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.LastTransaction</th>
                        @*<th>@Website.LocalResource.Resource.Detail</th>*@
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.AtmTransactionList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @if (@item.RateOfsuccessfulTransaction >= 70 && @item.TransactionsCount > 0)
                            {
                                <td><small><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" disabled>Good</button></small></td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (@item.RateOfsuccessfulTransaction < 70 && @item.TransactionsCount > 0)
                                {
                                    <td><small><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" disabled>Warning</button></small></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td><small><button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-xs" disabled>Inactive</button></small></td>
                                }
                            }
                            <td>@item.AtmId @item.AtmName</td>

                            <td>@item.RateOfsuccessfulTransaction %</td>

                            <td>@item.TransactionsCount</td>
                            <td>@item.TransactionRetrait</td>
                            @*<td>@item.TransactionWithoutCard</td>
                                <td>@item.TransactionCard</td>*@
                            <td>@item.OtherOption</td>
                            <td>@item.LastTransaction</td>

                            <!--<td class="">-->
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", 1, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })*@
                            <!--<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-assigned-id="@item.AtmId" onclick="javascript:DetailTrns(@("\"")@item.AtmId@("\""));" value="Detail" />
                            </td>-->
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>



</body>

<style>

    .breakhere {
        page-break-after: always
    }

    table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
</style>




<!-- Mainly scripts -->


<script src="~/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app-assets/js/scripts/charts/apexcharts/charts-apexcharts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var doc = document.getElementById("Html");
            var htm = document.getElementById("trxReportDiv");
            var M = " ";
            M += htm.outerHTML;
            doc.setAttribute("value", M);

        });



    </script>

    @*///////////////////////////// chart_transaction_type ////////////////////////////////*@
    <script>

    var data3 =  @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TransactionTypeGraphData));
    var chartData = $.map(data3, function (obj, i) { return { "name": obj.label, "y": obj.count, "drilldown": obj.color }; });

    Highcharts.chart('chart_transaction_type', {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        colors: $.map(data3, function (obj, i) { return [obj.color]; }),
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Percentage',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: chartData,
            }
        ]
    });




    </script>


    @*///////////////////////////// chart_Motif_Rejet ////////////////////////////////*@
    <script>
    var data3 =  @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RejectedTransactionList));
    var chartData = $.map(data3, function (obj, i) { return { "name": obj.label, "y": obj.count, "drilldown": obj.color }; });

    Highcharts.chart('chart_Motif_Rejet', {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        colors: $.map(data3, function (obj, i) { return [obj.color]; }),

        series: [
            {
                name: 'Percentage',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: chartData,
            }
        ]
    });

    </script>
```

I tried generating a PDF using Rotativa in my ASP.NET MVC application, including charts. However, the charts are not showing up in the PDF, even though the tables and other data display correctly. I expected both the tables and charts to be included in the generated PDF.

Comment: I am not familiar with Rotativa, however in case of exporting Highcharts, consider using the export module https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview